# Laravel Ajax Search Query Param Issue

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to create/learn ajax search results using Laravel. Im at the following stage where I can get the data from the DB but the query string appears to not be captured into the controller and querying the data. I expect its an issue with my Ajax or where I am posting the data from the view to the URL. I am new to Laravel so any advice will be welcome. Thanks

search.blade.php

```
            <form class="navbar-search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control bg-lightblue border-0 small text-white border-dark" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"></button>

            </form>

        <div class="col-md-12">

                <table class="table table-hover table-responsive-sm">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Total Data : <span id="total_records"></span></th>
                        <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Immediate Contact</th>
                        <th scope="col">Address</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

        </div>

    </div>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            fetch_customer_data();

            function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
            {

                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('search.action') }}",
                    //url: 'user-figures/action',
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: {"query":query},
                    dataType:'json',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
                        $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
                    }
                })

            }

        });

    </script>
```

Controller

```
public function ajaxindex()
    {
        return view('search.index');
    }

public function ajaxaction(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $total_row = '';
            $output = '';

            $query = $request->get('query');
            if($query != '')
            {
                $data = figures::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->get();
            }
            else
            {
                $data = figures::orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->get();
            }

            $total_row = $data->count();

            if($total_row > 0)
            {
                foreach($data as $row)
                {
                    $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
                        <td>poopppp</td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $output = '
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
            $data = array(
                'table_data' => $output,
                'total_data' => $total_row
            );
            return response()->json($data);
          //  $str_data = implode(" ", $data);

          //  echo $str_data;
        }
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/search', 'figuresController@ajaxindex')->name('search');
Route::get('/search/action', 'figuresController@ajaxaction')->name('search.action');
```

Comment: Is search action supposed to be a post route instead of a get route?  In the ajax action method are you supposed to be returning the results to a view? (I'm new to Laravel too)

Comment: The routes should be correct as I got them from a tutorial and some information on this site. The results should come back to the view, if there is no query it will just return all the data from the table. The data is coming back from the DB, but the query string is being lost somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and followed this tutorial https://www.cloudways.com/blog/live-search-laravel-ajax/ and have got this to work.  Here is my full code and hopefully you can figure out how to get yours working

Search controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Product;
class SearchController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
{
return view('search.index');
}
public function search(Request $request)
{
if($request->ajax())
{
$output="";
$products=DB::table('products')->where('title','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
if($products)
{
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
$output.='<tr>'.
'<td>'.$product->id.'</td>'.
'<td>'.$product->title.'</td>'.
'<td>'.$product->description.'</td>'.
'<td>'.$product->price.'</td>'.
'</tr>';
}
return Response($output);
   }
   }
}
}
```

Just one view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<title>Live Search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3>Products info </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-controller" id="search" name="search"></input>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#search').on('keyup',function(){
$value=$(this).val();
$.ajax({
type : 'get',
url : '{{URL::to('search/action')}}',
data:{'search':$value},
success:function(data){
$('tbody').html(data);
}
});
})
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/search','SearchController@index');
Route::get('/search/action','SearchController@search')->name('search.action');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I could get this to work but it uses different functions to what I believe modern Laravel should do by returning a json response. Im also trying to load all data when a search has not been initiated. I am very new to this so trying to cobble a few functions/outcomes from this basic tutorial.